# Specifying several independent priors in stan_glm() in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stan

I am using the function `stan_glm()` in R. I am using 4 predictor variables and I want to specify a univariate independent prior for each regression parameter. Right now I am trying to include each prior by placing them in a list through the following code snippet:

```
  poisson.model.stan <- stan_glm(Count ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4, 
                                 family = poisson(link=log),
                                  data=data,
                                 chains = 4, cores = 5, seed = 55, iter = 100000,
                                 offset=log(exposure), prior_intercept = normal(-2,1), 
                                 prior = c(normal(-0.2, 0.05),
                                           normal(0.1, 0.05),
                                           normal(0.3, 0.05),
                                           normal(0.04, 0.05)))
```

However, I am not sure whether this is the correct way of specifying my priors.
To summarize, how do I specify several independent priors in the `stan_glm()` function?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstanarm/vignettes/priors.html?

Comment: @DemetriPananos yes, I checked that page but did not find anything useful unfortunately

Comment: at the bottom of the page the authors indicate that coefficients are given a multivariate normal prior.  Consequently `prior=normal(c(-0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4), 0.05)` should work.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Thank you! That solved my issue

Comment: @DemetriPananos: That is the correct syntax, although it is still a product of univariate priors, rather than a multivariate (normal) prior.

Comment: @BenGoodrich Thank you for the response! Your answer is correct. If you post it as a response I'll mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: @BenGoodrich OP says they want a univariate independent prior for each regression param.  Is there a preference for multivariate normal rather than the product of independent normals?

Comment: There are reasons to prefer one or the other, but rstanarm only implements independent priors.